# MySQL DATE_FORMAT duplicate specifiers

Tags: mysql, date-format

Can somebody explain the [difference between the `%h` and `%I`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)? Both are described as "Hour (01..12)" and the same with seconds `%s` and `%S`? It is any 'strange' functionality behind that? What's the reason to have that duplicated?

Answer (score 2):

%h and %I, as well as %s and %S are identical.

In the code it looks like this:

```
case 'h':
case 'I':
  hours_i= (l_time->hour%24 + 11)%12+1;
  length= (uint) (int10_to_str(hours_i, intbuff, 10) - intbuff);
  str->append_with_prefill(intbuff, length, 2, '0'); 
  break;

case 'S':
case 's':
  sprintf(intbuff,"%02d",l_time.second);
  str->append(intbuff);
  break;
```

Even as far back as in version 3.23.57 (oldest source archive I could find) which was released 20th June 2003 they were identical.

Comment: any reason why? ...not important - just curious ;-)